# What does QueryAsync() return when requesting 1..N values from a single string column?

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq-to-sql, async-await, return-type

With this code (with or without the ".ToList()"):

```
public async Task<List<String>> SelectDistinctGroupNames()
{
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
    var groupNames = await db.QueryAsync<List<string>>("SELECT DISTINCT GroupName FROM SOs_Locations");
    return groupNames.ToList();
}
```

...I get, "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'*"

This works:

```
public async Task<HashSet<String>> SelectDistinctGroupNames()
{
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
    var allLocations = await db.QueryAsync<SOs_Locations>("SELECT * FROM SOs_Locations ORDER BY GroupName");
    HashSet<string> hashsetGroupNames = null;
    foreach (var item in allLocations)
    {
        hashsetGroupNames.Add(item.GroupName);
    }
    return hashsetGroupNames;
}
```

...but seems wasteful (grabbing all the records, when all I want is distinct values from the GroupName column).

It seems to me that what is needed is a List or even a HashSet when replacing the "*" in the sql query with a "DISTINCT GroupName"

So what exactly is returned when a single column from several records is returned? IOW, what should be within the angle brackets of the call to QueryAsync<>() ?

I would think that this would work:

```
public async Task<List<String>> SelectDistinctGroupNames()
{
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
    List<string> allLocations = await db.QueryAsync<string>("SELECT DISTINCT GroupName FROM SOs_Locations ORDER BY GroupName");
    return allLocations;
}
```

...but with that I get, "*'string' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection.QueryAsync(string, params object[])'*"

I had a "string" above to correspond with `<SOs_Locations`> (not "List`<SOs_Locations`>") in the working version of the method. When I change it to "List`<string`>", I get, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`<System.Collections.Generic.List`' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List`<string`>'"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the source](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLiteAsync.cs):

```
public Task<List<T>> QueryAsync<T> (string sql, params object[] args)
        where T : new ()
```

So if you want `List<string>` as a result, you would need to pass `string` for `T`. As you noticed, `string` cannot satisfy a `new()` constraint (because it does not have a parameterless constructor), so that's not possible.

I took a look through the code and it looks to me like the `new()` constraint is unnecessary, so my first stop would be with the sqlite-net folks asking them to remove it (and verifying that `T=string` will work).

In the meantime, you should be able to create a type for the result of this query:

```
public sealed class DistinctGroupNamesResult
{
  public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

and use a brief transformation:

```
public async Task<List<String>> SelectDistinctGroupNames()
{
  var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
  var result = await db.QueryAsync<DistinctGroupNamesResult>("SELECT DISTINCT GroupName FROM SOs_Locations");
  return result.Select(x => x.GroupName).ToList();
}
```

There may be simpler solutions, e.g., using the higher-level LINQ provider (not sure if it supports `DISTINCT`, though). Or it may be possible to use `SOs_Locations` as the result type instead of `DistinctGroupNamesResult`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
List<String> resultString = new List<string>(); 
var result = await db.QueryAsync<DistinctGroupNamesResult>("SELECT * FROM SOs_Locations");

foreach (string item in result.Select(x=> x.GroupName).Distinct())
{
    resultString.Add(item);
}

return resultString;
```